# How can I make this print as a list eg. [1, 3, 5, 7]?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all of the odd numbers in the range (1,30) in Python as a list, but I can't get it to work how I want it to. This is my code:

```
myrange = list(range(1,30))
for i in myrange:
    if i % 2 != 0:
        mylist = list([str(i)])
        print(mylist)
```

This is what prints:

```
['3']
['5']
['7']
['9']
['11']
['13']
['15']
['17']
['19']
['21']
['23']
['25']
['27']
['29']
```

However, I want it to print as a list like:
 `[1, 3, 5 ,7...]`

I can't figure out how to do this despite looking at numerous articles online!

Comment: Create a blank list before the loop.  Append to the list in the loop.  Print the list after the loop.

Comment: Why do you call `str` when you don't want a string? and why do you print in each iteration when you want to print only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create your list of odd numbers.

```
mylist = [i for i in myrange if i % 2 != 0]
print(mylist)
```

Or better yet, just have [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) skip the even numbers itself:

```
myrange = range(1, 31, 2)
print(list(myrange))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!